# Read TFS/VSTS Secreat Variables in Task written in Typescript

Tags: typescript, tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to read password values defined under predefined variables in **typescript**

[image]

I am reading plain text variables using below notation.

```
import tl = require('vsts-task-lib/task');
var password = tl.getVariable("amiprotacted");
```

I need to know method to read secret variables. And whether if there is method to segregate plain text and secret values?.Please be kind enough to show some light.

I am currently referring to https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables#secret-variables article regarding secret variables (however there is no example available to do this using Typescript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t read secret variables in the code, you need to pass then through input box of task. So you can add a input to let user to pass secret variables and get the value by using getInput/getPathInput etc... [VSTS-TASK-LIB TYPESCRIPT API](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/node/docs/azure-pipelines-task-lib.md#taskgetInput)

> Secret variables are:
>
> • Encrypted at rest with a 2048-bit RSA key.
>
> • Not returned back to the client. They are automatically masked out
>   of any log output from the build or release.
>
> • Not decrypted into environment variables. So scripts and programs
>   run by your build steps are not given access by default.
>
> • Decrypted for access by your build steps. So you can use them in
>   password arguments (for example Build and Deploy your Java application
>   to an Azure web app and also pass them explicitly into a script or a
>   program from your build step (for example as $(password)).

Comment: Thanks a lot @starain-MSFT